# how to calculate combinations of elements in groups?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many combinations there are if I have 1 or 0 in a set of 6 elements with the possibility to group them in two (then three, four five and six elements)and in each group must be the same value?

Example:

If I have six numbers, and these numbers can be just 0 or 1 ($|N|=6$ and $N \in \{0,1\}$).
I wrote an example for 2 and 3 groups but I need all possible groups until 6(one element for one group).

With $|groups|=2$ I'm interested in (without repetition, see the following note):

Groups 1+5:

$G_{1}=\{1\}$ and $G_{2}=\{1,1,1,1,1\}$

$G_{1}=\{1\}$ and $G_{2}=\{0,0,0,0,0\}$

$G_{1}=\{0\}$ and $G_{2}=\{1,1,1,1,1\}$

$G_{1}=\{0\}$ and $G_{2}=\{0,0,0,0,0\}$

Groups 2+4 (note: I'm not interested in 4+2):

$G_{1}=\{1,1\}$ and $G_{2}=\{1,1,1,1\}$

$G_{1}=\{1,1\}$ and $G_{2}=\{0,0,0,0\}$

$G_{1}=\{0,0\}$ and $G_{2}=\{0,0,0,0\}$

$G_{1}=\{0,0\}$ and $G_{2}=\{1,1,1,1\}$

Groups 3+3:

$G_{1}=\{1,1,1\}$ and $G_{2}=\{1,1,1\}$

$G_{1}=\{0,0,0\}$ and $G_{2}=\{0,0,0\}$

$G_{1}=\{1,1,1\}$ and $G_{2}=\{0,0,0\}$ (note: I'm not interested in $G_{1}=\{0,0,0\}$ $G_{2}=\{1,1,1\}$)

With $|groups|=3$ I'm interested in (without repetition):

Groups 1+1+4:

$G_{1}=\{1\}$, $G_{2}=\{1\}$ and $G_{3}=\{1,1,1,1\}$

$G_{1}=\{1\}$, $G_{2}=\{1\}$ and $G_{3}=\{0,0,0,0\}$

$G_{1}=\{1\}$, $G_{2}=\{0\}$ and $G_{3}=\{1,1,1,1\}$

$G_{1}=\{1\}$, $G_{2}=\{0\}$ and $G_{3}=\{0,0,0,0\}$

$G_{1}=\{0\}$, $G_{2}=\{0\}$ and $G_{3}=\{0,0,0,0\}$

$G_{1}=\{0\}$, $G_{2}=\{0\}$ and $G_{3}=\{1,1,1,1\}$

Groups 1+2+3:

$G_{1}=\{1\}$, $G_{2}=\{1,1\}$ and $G_{3}=\{1,1,1\}$

$G_{1}=\{1\}$, $G_{2}=\{1,1\}$ and $G_{3}=\{0,0,0\}$

$G_{1}=\{1\}$, $G_{2}=\{0,0\}$ and $G_{3}=\{1,1,1\}$

$G_{1}=\{1\}$, $G_{2}=\{0,0\}$ and $G_{3}=\{0,0,0\}$

$G_{1}=\{0\}$, $G_{2}=\{1,1\}$ and $G_{3}=\{1,1,1\}$

$G_{1}=\{0\}$, $G_{2}=\{1,1\}$ and $G_{3}=\{0,0,0\}$

$G_{1}=\{0\}$, $G_{2}=\{0,0\}$ and $G_{3}=\{0,0,0\}$

$G_{1}=\{0\}$, $G_{2}=\{0,0\}$ and $G_{3}=\{1,1,1\}$

Groups 2+2+2:

$G_{1}=\{1,1\}$, $G_{2}=\{1,1\}$ and $G_{3}=\{1,1\}$

$G_{1}=\{1,1\}$, $G_{2}=\{0,0\}$ and $G_{3}=\{0,0\}$

$G_{1}=\{1,1\}$, $G_{2}=\{1,1\}$ and $G_{3}=\{0,0\}$

$G_{1}=\{0,0\}$, $G_{2}=\{0,0\}$ and $G_{3}=\{0,0\}$

Which is the general formula to calculate all the combinations for each cardinality of groups with any N?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are just asking for the number of ways to sum up to 6 with two partitions, and then "paint" each group with 0 or 1, independently. The last part gives a factor of 4 (in general, $2^{\text{number of groups}}$). Splitting a number into summands where order is important is called *combinations* of that number, so you want the number of combinations with 2 parts of 6. They are:
$$6 = 1 + 5 = 2 + 4 = 3 + 3 = 4 + 2 = 5 + 1$$
Splitting $n$ into 2 parts can be done in $n - 1$ ways (the first addend ranges from 1 to $n - 1$), so the total would be $4 (n - 1)$, or 20 if $n = 6$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was looking at n-1.. in general, splitting n into x parts it is not n-1 (for example for 3 is not 5 but 10).Which is the formula?and, there is a way to remove the repetitions like I sad in the example?